# what do you call a person who always goes out of their way to fulfill other's needs,

Tags: idioms

what do you call a person who always goes out of their way to fulfill other's needs, such as caring for kids of a sick person, bank rolling friends, taking a friends kids all the time, paying for meals/gifts to look good around their peers.

Comment: Can you provide more context about how you would use this word or phrase, including a sample sentence (with an X or ___ to show where the word would go)?  You list a lot of example situations and then, at the end, add _to look good around their peers._  How important is that to the word or phrase you're looking for?  That is, are you talking about a person who just does that sort of thing or someone who only does it to look good?

Comment: I wasn't sure they would, but some dictionaries include **extra-miler**.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of person can be described using words that have either a positive connotation or a negative one. For example, **angel** could be used positively, or **brown-noser** could be used negatively. A more neutral word would be **altruist**. I take it by your last example, you are looking for a word with a negative sense.

The negative sense could be further divided into self-abasement: He treats her terribly, but then expects her to be his personal servant. And she does it. She's such a dishrag. Or it could be divided into obsequious: The minute he found out my friend was the boss's son, his whole demeanor changed. He's such a **suck-up**. Or, vulgarly (the word has the meaning of sticking one's nose up someone else's butt), **brown-noser**.

Answer (score 0):

An idiom to denote the *action* of "`going out of their way to fulfill other's needs`" is ***bending over backwards***.

TFD(idioms):

> **[bend over backwards](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bend+over+backwards)** (to do something) (for someone)
>   *Fig*. to work very hard to accomplish something for someone; **to go out of one's way** (to do something) (for someone).
>
> He will bend over backwards to help you.
>
> McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002 by
>   The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc.